# is it possible to use a service into a typescript class in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have a class as follows which is not annotated with @Injectable

```
export class A extends B {

    calculateTotal(): number {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

The above function calculateTotal needs to use a service which is annotated with @Injectable to be able to get some values to perform some totals. Question is: is it ok to use that service into that class?

Ashley

Comment: Yes, it is ok and documented: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection  . Can you please elaborate a bit your question? It's not so clear what you're asking.

Comment: @PaoloStefan edited my question

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to get one `SomeService` instance injected into `class A`. The one I use e.g. in Ionic 2 is:

- if class A can be a Component, add the `@Component` decorator to its definition and the `providers` metadata to it;
- import the service definition in the `class A` definition file;
- add a constructor method to `class A` and declare a service instance as argument.

For example, assuming that the service class is named `SomeService` and is defined in the file `some.service.ts` in the same directory as the current source file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService } from './some.service';

@Component({
    providers: [ SomeService ]
})
export class A extends B {

    constructor( public s:SomeService ){}

    otherMethod(){
        this.s; // SomeService is accessible like this
    }
}
```

More information is available in [the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).